# What C++ IDEs on Linux have "intellisense" in par with, or better, than Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, ide

There are some Linux based C++ projects in the pipe. What IDEs should I go for that have some kind of "intellisense" in par with, or better, than the one of a bare Visual Studio (that is, without the Visual Assist steroids).

(Note that I didn't use the words "as good as, or better". I consider the Visual Studio C++ intellisense everything but good, hence the "in par with" words and Visual Assist comment).

Comment: I'm also told that no other IDE comes close to VS's ease of debugging.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

None. [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) and [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/) are popular choices, but they have nothing on VS.

Comment: I should add that the recent Qt Creator 2.1 has significantly improved behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

[Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/) hands down.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of years ago I did C++ programming in Eclipse with the CDT extension and I gotta say it did a reasonably good job with its intellisense-like feature. Certainly on par with VC++, probably better. As this was in 2008, chances are they have improved it since then.

Comment: +1.  Eclipse's indexing and discovery can be tricky to get working, but once it works, it's quite nice.

Answer (score 4):

The best completion in my experience has QTCreator (don't be scared by the name, it doesn't require you to use QT).

Answer (score 4):

Well, I use SlickEdit. Yes, it's not free, but it's the best I found. I tried many others, but Slick is just much, much better. 
KDevelop is nice, too, and it's free, but SE is better to me. About Visual Studio - I still think that it's just the best. Its intellisense is brilliant, the debugger too.

Answer (score 3):

I generally like [KDevelop 4](http://www.kdevelop.org/) a lot and their code-completition is pretty good, too :) Also it integrates nicely with gdb. You can read some more about it in the [release statement](http://dot.kde.org/2010/05/01/kdevelop-40-stable-released-wild)

Answer (score 3):

Although it's not better than VS, NetBeans works quite well for me.

Comment: I didn't know that NetBEans could do C++, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/). I think they already have a plugin for C++. I found this [article](http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Creating_C_and_CPP_Projects) out. :D

Comment: Too bad, looks ok otherwise: "It cannot yet resolve types of local variables, so does not work for class instance members using the '.' and '->' operators."

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i've done ALOT of research since I first read this question and although a top answer did get picked already, I felt I owed it to everyone else that was transitioning from Visual Studio/.NET/Windows to Linux and felt lost as I did -- thanks to [arscariousus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/436874/arscariosus) for his answer to get me going in the right direction.

First off, MonoDevelop is the program of choice if you are looking for the nearest 1:1 intellisense. In fact, using MonoDevelop 4.0, it almost looks like Visual Studio in many ways. I was very suprised that nobody was talking more about this until I found out one problem: there was no MonoDevelop 4 package for linux of any flavor, just windows (BAH!). I was discouraged but found that i COULD use it because all I had to do was download the source for 4.0 and compile it (took about an hour give or take) but when it was done, it works great.. I have successfully built the Mono 4.0.1 package for Ubuntu Studio 13.04 amd64, if anyone wants it let me know --- i was unable to find a precompiled package but maybe there is one out there, this is probably why other ppl dont suggest it. I spent alot of side-time in Qt, but it sucks learning a new environment if you already know .NET well though QtCreator does seem to be a good MFC via VC++ substitute strictly linux speaking --- but Qtcreator leaves much to be desired for intellisense which is where it falls short. MonoDevelop makes learning the other parts of the gtk toolkit that it encompases much easier and pretty much was exactly what i was looking for. Maybe other ppl dont like it but it is definately best in my opinion.

The Verdict--- MonoDevelop 4.0 hands down because the intellisense is almost exactly like Visual Studio not to mention some of the other features, keybindings, layout, etc.

You can get the source right from their homepage, and gist has some scripts to explain how to make the debian pkgs if you use debian/ubuntu. I'm sure there's probably some gist snippet for your specific l-distro as well. Hope this helps...