# Which IDE are you using under Unix/Linux for visual debugging?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, unix, ide

I usually build the application in windows and test /port the application in UNIX using VI 
But what is I need to build the application from scratch in unix/linux in shell what option do I have to
Visually debug (break point and such .. )  or syntax helpers?  ( c/c++)

Answer (score 5):

[QtCreator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/) is excellent for Qt development. It is integrated well with gdb, has all the normal features plus excellent source control integration as well. Also [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/) is very good. Of course, [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) isn't bad either.

Comment: +1, QtCreator great not only for Qt, but any C/C++ project

Answer (score 2):

I am old school, I grew up using ed (yes, ed) moved to vi, and then emacs. I occasionally fall back to emacs now and again when I want to do something that needs the power of emacs.

But lately I've been using [Netbeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/) and loving it for all the code completion and easy access to function signatures. I can learn one IDE and use it for shell, Java, C, C++, HTML, CSS, Javascript, and Python. These are the languages I use most. 
Netbeans is cross-platform and written in Java. It's fast enough on most processors of today.

I've heard great things about [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), but as I use many other languages I don't want to learn another IDE just for C/C++ language. Although it probably has an emacs mode for me :). Code::Blocks is written in C++ so it's going to be a fast IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/features).

> - Full breakpoints support
> - Syntax highlighting, customizable and extensible
> - Code completion
> - etc...

Answer (score 1):

I've used [`Netbeans`](http://netbeans.org/features/cpp/) it has the GNU debugger integrated in it.

You'll find a [good comparisons of all the IDE's for C and C++ here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.2FC.2B.2B)

Answer (score 1):

Try [DDD - Data Display Debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/).

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820390/what-c-ides-on-linux-have-intellisense-in-par-with-or-better-than-visual-st/3820890#3820890) stands equally for visual debugging.